# Which headset to replace my FSA No.10?

Tags: parts, headset

I have a Cube LTD CC (2009 model) which has [this semi-integrated headset](http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=68774) in it. It needs replacing, but I'd rather go for something with cartridge bearings instead of cage bearings.

I've been looking around on the Cane Creek website trying to work out what might be compatible but don't know the measurements (don't really want to dismantle the headset if I can avoid it). Seems I need a ZS headset of some sort, but that's all I know. What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a standard 1-1/8in headset to me? The gold standard is the Chris King NoThreadSet. Sealed cartridge bearings, lasts damn near forever.

Comment: It's not an external headset, though, so I thought external headsets like that won't be compatible?

Comment: Ah, apologies. The page linked to didn't indicate it wasn't a standard external headset, and I wasn't able to find any information about that headset specifically. Wonder if I can downvote my own reply...

Comment: Nope. I cannot.

Comment: Not to worry – should've been more specific in my question!